# How do I format "if val 1 or 4 or 6 or 10"

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have some jquery that checks for the value of a form select and then does something. It works as expected, as follows:

```
$("#field_1_select_value").bind('change', function (e) { 
  if($("#field_1_select_value").val() == 1){

  // Do stuff

  } else {

  // Do something else

  }         
});
```

I would like to check if the select has other values because the behavior would be the same if you choose a number of different options in the select, and they are not necessarily in series so I can't say greater than or less than X. I want to specify if you choose, for example, 1, 4, 10, or 20... something happens. I tried just using commas based on another answer I found elsewhere like follows:

```
if($("#field_1_select_value").val() == 1, 4, 10, 20){
```

But that didn't seem to work. The `,` acts as a multiselector as I understand it and in documentation it makes sense but I didn't find much on how it can work in an `if` statement scenario like this. I've seen a lot of similar questions but nothing really pointing out usage on an `if` statement with `val`.

Thanks for your input and suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

arrays have an [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) property you can use.  Just be sure to convert the value from `field_1_select_value` to a number, instead of the string you'll otherwise get back.

The fastest way to do this is with the unary `+` operator.

```
if([1, 4, 10, 20].indexOf(+$("#field_1_select_value").val()) >= 0){
```

Answer (score 8):

A switch case may suit your needs:

```
switch (parseInt($("#field_1_select_value").val(), 10)) {
case 1:
case 4:
case 10:
case 20:
    // do stuff
    break;
default:
    // do something else
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuerys [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/):

```
if($.inArray(+$('#field_1_select_value').val(), [1, 4, 10, 20]) > -1)
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/we6ozdhs/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try something like this:

```
// this way it's easy to insert new values in case of possible 
// changes in the future
var posNums = [1,2,3,4]; 
var val = $("#field_1_select_value").val()

if(posNumbs.indexOf(val) >= 0){
  //some actions
}{
  //other actions
}
```